# Problem removing APFS partition

Tags: terminal, bootcamp, disk-utility, windows, partition

A few months ago I tried to install Windows 10 on my Mac (High Sierra). This  was unsuccessful and left me with a APFS partition of 49.5 GB called "BC1".

[image]

When I try to delete this partition it says this:

[image]

I already tried to delete it in Recovery Mode and even reset my Mac once.

This is what comes up when I type "diskutil list" in the terminal:

[image]

I have tried *many* different terminal commands already but in the end it always leaves me with this BC1 partition. I guess that's my punishment for trying to install Windows on a Mac. How can I remove it?

Comment: Can I assume you can boot from the external drive? If so, which version of macOS?

Comment: @DavidAnderson I suppose I could but don't know how... I use MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6